# Are there any simple javascript spreadsheet widgets?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, spreadsheet

I need to create a simple web-based expense calculator.  We're using asp.net web forms, and each cell will be a text box.  The goal is to persist each value (but not the totals) to a database - so I'll have an expense table, and an expense_day table which will have the values for each row of text boxes.

There will be a week's worth of rows, and 6-8 columns. Each row needs to be totaled up, as does each column.

Is there a simple javascript framework that will do this?  We're already using jquery, but I don't mind including another small specialized library if it will make this functionality easy.

Update:

Something like the solution described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360115/using-jquery-to-get-per-row-totals-and-grand-total-of-table) expanded to also total columns would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [jQuery spreadsheet.](http://visop-dev.com/lib/jquery/jquery.sheet/jquery.sheet.html)

It looks like it uses Themeroller, which is pretty neat.

Comment: It looks interesting, if waaaayyy overkill for what I need.

Comment: @chris, maybe your initial feature request was underkill? :)

Comment: Here is another jquery plugin.
http://www.bossanova.uk/jexcel/tracking-changes-on-the-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You could start with [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/), and then use its API to add a row containing the totals.

Comment: All of the data is user-provided, so I don't know that DataTables will help.

Comment: @chris ouch, I think you should specify that in the question. If you already have the user input part working caclulating the sums and putting them in the appropriate cells should not be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably still more complex than you need, but the ExtJS data grids could do what you want:

Here is a demo using their editable data grid (doesn't calculate totals):
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html

Here is a demo that calculates totals at the bottom. (It's also demonstrating grouping, which you can probably ignore):
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/totals.html

You can see the rest of their samples here: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-3

They have screencasts showing how to use their grid controls:
http://www.sencha.com/learn/Screencasts