# hide table rows and table columns if sum =0

Tags: jquery

In jquery i found several ways to recover all values in a table (`tr>td`), sum the rows, column by column,  and hide the rows with `sum=0`.

Also,  I need to sum all the `td` values row by row (`td>tr`) and if `sum=0`, hide the column.

Whats the shortest way to get it?

**UPDATE:**
There's my current code:

```
<table id='mytable' >
<tr><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
<input type='button' onclick='updateTotal()' value='row sum'>

<script>
function updateTotal() {
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
for (var r = 0, n=table.rows.length ; r < n; r++) {
    mysum=0;
    for (var x = 0, y = table.rows[r].cells.length; x < y; x++) {
        mysum=mysum+parseFloat(table.rows[r].cells[x].innerHTML);
    }
    if(mysum==0)    alert((r+1)+" row hide it!");
}
for (var r = 0, n=table.rows[0].cells.length ; r < n; r++) {
    mysum=0;
    for (var x = 0, y = table.rows.length; x < y; x++) {
        mysum=mysum+parseFloat(table.rows[x].cells[r].innerHTML);
    }
    if(mysum==0)    alert((r+1)+" col hide it!");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360115/using-jquery-to-get-per-row-totals-and-grand-total-of-table you have  a basis to do that on javascript, but jquery can shorten the code?

Comment: jQuery is a very useful library, so of course it will shorten the code by handling some of the tedious repetitive stuff for you (like finding dom elements). See my answer!

Comment: Alek, theres my current code.

Comment: My code shows you how to do the second for loop in an easier way... can you specify exactly what you want me to explain?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following HTML for the table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can do the processing that you want for the columns in a way that I'm guessing very similar to the way you're processing the rows, here's some example JavaScript (I"m using jQuery):

```
$(function(){

    var list = $("table tr td:nth-child(2)"); 
    var sum = 0;
    for(var l = 0; l<list.length; l++)
        sum += parseInt($(list[l]).text());

    if(sum == 12)
    {
        list.css('background-color', 'green');
        //list.hide();
    }
    else
        list.css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxDD8/

**update:**

To address your inquiry as to how jQuery can help you reduce code consider:

1. Let's take `table.rows[r].cells[x].innerHTML` in your code as an example. If you want to use jQuery, you can jus say $("#tableName tr td:nth-child(3)"). You'll need to construct a string object with the `r` and `x` variables!

Comment: Thanks, Mzn. Your answer is half way what I need. Look the update code i posted and note the column *and* row analysis. Im wondering if I can  shorten heavily the code using jquery, or just leave it on javascript -and accept there are scenarios where javascript still rules-.

Comment: Okay I'll look into your update. BUT you must understand that jQuery is just a library. jQuery IS JavaScript. JavaScript always rules ;)

Comment: My code shows you how jQuery can spare you a lot of work already